# SensorManager.getOrientation returns values that are not in angles

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, magnetometer

I am trying to implement a business logic layer that tells me on what degree from 180 to -180 is the device currently is in the x axis. It will be used for a camera screen that requires the user to hold the phone vertically.

So in order to do so, I listens to both the `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and to the `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` sensors types as suggested in the official docs -

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position#sensors-pos-prox

And I ended up with the following code -

```kotlin
override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
         val value = event?.values ?: return@onSensorChanged
         var accelerometerReading = floatArrayOf()
         var magnetometerReading = floatArrayOf()

          when(event.sensor.type) {
                TYPE_ACCELEROMETER -> {
                    accelerometerReading = floatArrayOf(value[0], value[1], value[2])
                }
                TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD -> {
                    magnetometerReading = floatArrayOf(value[0], value[1], value[2])
                }
            }

            val rotationMatrix = FloatArray(9)
            if (magnetometerReading.isEmpty() || accelerometerReading.isEmpty()) return@setOnSensorValuesChangedListener
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, FloatArray(9), accelerometerReading, magnetometerReading)
            val orientationAngles = FloatArray(3)
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationAngles) //always returns the same values that are provided to it. why?
```

As you can see, I implemented the exact same code as said to do in the official docs but the values I get have nothing to do in the range of 180 to -180 in both 3 of the elements in the `orientationAngles` array. I get values that are very similar to the input I give it, something like `[-0.051408034, -0.007878973, 0.04735359]` which is some random irrelevant data for me.

Any idea why would this happen and how to indeed get what I want which is the x axis angle of the device?

Edit:

I'll try to simplify what I want.

Imagine holding a device in portrait mode locked in with it facing you. In a perfect portrait stance I want to get a 90 degree value from the sensor. When the user tilts the device either left or right the values would either go down to 0 or up to 180 (which side it is doesn't matter). All I need is these 2 dimensional x axis values.

Answer (score 2):

It gives the angles in radians, not degrees.  Almost nothing in math uses degrees beyond grade school math, radians is the norm. Radians generally go from 0 to 2*pi, equaling 0 to 360 degrees.  The formula to convert is degrees= radians/pi * 180

According to docs, the angles returned by getOrientation returns radians in the range -PI to PI, where 0 is defined by the individual angles.  From the docs:

> 

```
values[0]: Azimuth, angle of rotation about the -z axis. This value represents the angle between the device's y axis and the magnetic north pole. When facing north, this angle is 0, when facing south, this angle is π. Likewise, when facing east, this angle is π/2, and when facing west, this angle is -π/2. The range of values is -π to π.
values[1]: Pitch, angle of rotation about the x axis. This value represents the angle between a plane parallel to the device's screen and a plane parallel to the ground. Assuming that the bottom edge of the device faces the user and that the screen is face-up, tilting the top edge of the device toward the ground creates a positive pitch angle. The range of values is -π/2 to π/2.
values[2]: Roll, angle of rotation about the y axis. This value represents the angle between a plane perpendicular to the device's screen and a plane perpendicular to the ground. Assuming that the bottom edge of the device faces the user and that the screen is face-up, tilting the left edge of the device toward the ground creates a positive roll angle. The range of values is -π to π.
```

Comment: I used the formula you gave me, creating a variable:
` val degrees = orientationAngles[1] / Math.PI * 180` but I get degrees in values from 85 ± to -85 ±, I need the range between 180 to -180 where 90 / -90 is the device in perfect portrait stance

Comment: @AlonShlider That's the correct formula, check anywhere on the web.  It's generally taught in the first week of a high school trig course.  If you're getting that answer, either you misimplemented it, you aren't actually achieving an angle higher than that, or your sensor is busted.

Comment: I rechecked the results and it indeed works but not as I wish it to work. I need the perfect vertical position to be 90 degrees value (which indeed what is happening now) and the horizontal position to be 180, so when you tilt the device to either left or right you either go down to 0 or up to 180, depending on the direction. Currently I when tilting at both directions I get values only ranging from 0 to 90.

Comment: @AlonShlider I'm not totally sure what value you're looking at, it sounds like pitch or roll?  You need to be more specific and talk in those terms,.  For pitch, a 0 is the phone screen facing straight up with its bottom near you.  Rotate it up so the screen faces to you, and you'll get PI/2.  Roll it down so the screen is away, and you get -PI/2,.    That's its entire range.  You won't get anyting outside of it.  If you rotate beyond that, you'll start converging back to a 0 when the phone is flat again.

Comment: Also, I forgot about this but Math.toDegrees will convert radians to degrees.  Although it's probably easier to just convert your app to thinking in radians and make change your constants.

Comment: I have edited the original post with the simplest explanation of what I need. I get what your saying about the correct mathematical way to relate to what I am looking for, but at the end what I want is the simple user friendly x axis degree values.

Comment: The problem with what you're describing is that's not how rotation works.  Imagine a phone.  The x-axis is the width.  The y is the height.  The z is going straight through the screen.  Moving it to face you and then turning it to left and right are rotations on two different axes.  Left/right would be rotation around the z axis, bringing it up to face you is rotation around the x.  The x, y, and z axes are relative to the phone, not to the world.